# Unity rewarded video ad registering multiple times. Unity Ads

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityads

This is my rewarded video script. It is attached to a `UI` button.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class RewardedAdsButton : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsListener
{

#if UNITY_IOS
    private string gameId = "1234567";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
    private string gameId = "7654321";
#endif

    Button myButton;
    public string myPlacementId = "rewardedVideo";

    void Start()
    {
        myButton = GetComponent<Button>();

        // Set interactivity to be dependent on the Placement’s status:
        myButton.interactable = Advertisement.IsReady(myPlacementId);

        // Map the ShowRewardedVideo function to the button’s click listener:
        if (myButton) myButton.onClick.AddListener(ShowRewardedVideo);

        // Initialize the Ads listener and service:
        Advertisement.AddListener(this);
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, true);
    }

    // Implement a function for showing a rewarded video ad:
    void ShowRewardedVideo()
    {
        Advertisement.Show(myPlacementId);
    }

    // Implement IUnityAdsListener interface methods:
    public void OnUnityAdsReady(string placementId)
    {
        // If the ready Placement is rewarded, activate the button: 
        if (placementId == myPlacementId)
        {
            myButton.interactable = true;
        }
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
    {
        // Define conditional logic for each ad completion status:
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "GameplayScene")
        {
            if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
            {
                GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManagerScript>().ResumeGame();
            }
            else if (showResult == ShowResult.Skipped)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("MenuScene");
            }
            else if (showResult == ShowResult.Failed)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("The ad did not finish due to an error.");
            }
        }
        if(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "CharacterScene")
        {
            if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coin", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coin", 0) + 50);
            }
            else if (showResult == ShowResult.Skipped)
            {
                //Do nothing.
            }
            else if (showResult == ShowResult.Failed)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("The ad did not finish due to an error.");
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidError(string message)
    {
        // Log the error.
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidStart(string placementId)
    {
        // Optional actions to take when the end-users triggers an ad.
    }
}
```

It should only add the 50 coins but on minimum it adds 100 or multiple of 50 times, the button is registering multiple clicks. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Using ads to generate revenue is not what video games are about. If your game isn't good enough to make money by itself, from just being a great game, then you shouldn't be making games. Treat this as constructive criticism. If you want to stand out from the crowd, don't use ads.

Comment: I don't get your point. You are saying either game should not be free to play or if it is then it should ask players to buy stuff to get advantage in the game? instead of serving ads. which whole point of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the code from unity website and so I was not sure what was going on. But here is the solution. We are subscribing to an event. And every time this script was called at the start of the scene, another new event was getting subscribed. So when you switch scene do "unsubscribe" to the event. And this issue will not happen.

Answer (score 5):

It is correct thirteen4054, for those who have the same problem, a possible solution is to add this method:

```
public void OnDestroy ()
{
   Advertisement.RemoveListener (this);
}
```

In this way, if you go to another scene and return to it, only the last element created will be subscribed.

---

@Nicola, I would not add it to the OnUnityAdsDidFinish because then the subscription would be removed after the first call regardless of the result.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem that I resolved adding this two lines:

```
Advertisement.RemoveListener (this);
myButton.onClick.RemoveListener(ShowRewardedVideo);
```

after the conditional logic for each ad completion status. 
The complete event should be like this:

```
   public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
    {
        // Define conditional logic for each ad completion status:
        if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
        {
            // Reward the user for watching the ad to completion.
        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Skipped)
        {
            // Do not reward the user for skipping the ad.

        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Failed)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("The ad did not finish due to an error.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error");
        }

        Advertisement.RemoveListener (this);
        myButton.onClick.RemoveListener(ShowRewardedVideo);
    }
```

I suggest to put the code even in the error event:

```
public void OnUnityAdsDidError (string message) 
{
    // Log the error.
    Advertisement.RemoveListener (this);
    myButton.onClick.RemoveListener(ShowRewardedVideo);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved this problem by calling OnDestry(), from OnUnityAdsShowStart(string adUnitId).  This gives appropriate follow and same amount of rewards on every click. ))